# File Handling C++ Error

Tags: c++, string, file, cin

I wanted write a program which allows users to write some random stuff, but i got an
error saying

```
 no matching call to
```

which I am not able to figure it out. please Help me.
while you are trying to answer to this question, try to be more noob specific.

here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string story;
    ofstream theFile;
 theFile.open("Random.txt");
 while(cin.get(story,5000)!=EOF)
{
    theFile<< story;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are having?

Comment: no matching call to "std::basic_istream<char>::get(std::) and some more"

Comment: Check [the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) - there's no overload of `istream::get` that takes `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

cin.get with 2 arguments expects `char*` as first argument and you are trying to pass `string` as the first argument.

If you want to read `std::string` instead of C-string until the end of line use `getline(cin, story)`

If you want to read string until the next space or newline or another blank symbol use `cin >> story;`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to write the content of cin to a file. You could just use stream operators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string story;
  ofstream theFile;
  theFile.open("Random.txt");

  if(cin >> story)
  {
    theFile << story.substr(0, 5000);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I am assuming that you only want the first 5000 characters in Random.txt...